# MongoDB query aggregation localField ObjectId string and foreign field ObjectId

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, objectid

My goal is to aggregate 2 collections where in one, namely the user collection,  I have an array of string type objectid that represent the actual ids in the other collection, namely the images collection.
im using the following code

```
    await dbConn()
    return User.aggregate([
       {
           $match:{_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}
       },
       {
           $unwind:'$imgIds'
       },

       {
           $lookup:{
               from:'images',
               localField:'imgIds',
               foreignField:'_id',
               as:'imgObjs'
           }
       }
    ],(err,res)=>console.log(res))
}
```

so there's a match of one item in the users collection. then deconstructing the imgIds array and trying to make the connection between the two with lookup whereas localField is a string and _id is an ObjectId.
The result is ImgObjs is an empty array.

Any thoughts about this one? 
**Im using version Mongo 3.6.12**

------------EDIT--------------

I found out something very strange in my server behavior. When im doing a simple findById call, my image item is an array of ObjectId.
But when using aggregate, the ObjecIds become String.
Anyone has any idea whats up here?

Comment: Can you share please samples for your collections?

Comment: ```{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e86209dd907804180cb4e11"
    },
    "title": "flowers",
    "url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dppogsm2u/image/upload/v1585763607/sample.jpg",
    "user": "5e86216947d8db4d9880ba9b",
    "__v": 0
}```{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e86216947d8db4d9880ba9b"
    },
    "following": [],
    "followers": [],
    "imgIds": [
        "5e86209dd907804180cb4e12"
    ],
    "name": "Josh",
    "email": "json@gmail.com",
    "password": "123456",
    "__v": 0
}

Comment: @DannyBorisOv : Either you've to upgrade to newer versions at least to `4.0` or latest `4.2`. Or you need to convert all those strings to `ObjectId()` in code & update all docs then you'll be able to do your `$lookup`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your strings to object IDs (or your object IDs to string).

**For Mongo version 4.0 or higher**

You can use `$toObjectId` to do this. In your case you can add an `$addFields` stage after your unwind:

```
{
  $addFields: {
    imgIdObjId: { $toObjectId: $imgIds }
  }
}
```

In your lookup you will need to use that field instead of `imgIds`:

```
{
  $lookup:{
    from:'images',
    localField:'imgIdObjId',
    foreignField:'_id',
    as:'imgObjs'
  }
}
```

For reference checkout: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/

Comment: From what i understood it's only possible from mongo 4. Either I could upgrade (which im not sure how to do) or there's an alternative way of doing so in previous versions. I believe this conversion is somehow possible also without the new feature of direct converting

Comment: Which mongo version are you using? Please add that to the question as well.

Comment: Running MongoDB version: 3.6.12